# Auto generate Id App Engine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How do you generate an Id in App engine datastore automatically?
I am using the automatically created Backend Function insertEntity().

As primary key I am using

```
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Long Id;
```

And when I call the insert function I would like that the datastore automatically assigns this Id...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, there is nothing wrong with what you have done. The ID will get generated automatically.

The problem I believe is the Auto Generated code that has been generated for the insertEntity() method. The code currently expects that the ID value has been provided and based on that, it first tries to retrieve an existing Entity. Since the ID is most likely null i.e. you have not passed it, it is resulting in an exception in the code.

Modify the code to check if the `getId() != null`. If not null, only then allow it to go forward, else just invoke the `makePersistent()` code.

Comment: Wow. Sometimes I am just too stupid for living.
The auto generated code checks if the entity is already in the datastore, because it assumes you deliver the Id. I just erased 
    if (containsArticle(article)) {
           throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
    }

Comment: You are welcome! I also suggest that you revisit the rest of the generated code. Additionally, I do believe that the containsArticle(...) code that they have is valuable, just that it needs a conditional check around it. Ideally you want that check so that you can throw back an exception in case the record already exists. You may also want to do you additional checks on other fields in case of determining if a similar record exists!